# Can I add both sides of a has_many and belongs_to relationship in a concern?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, relationship, activesupport-concern

**Edit: In retrospect this isn't that great of an idea. You are putting functionality that belongs to `ZipWithCBSA` into the models of others. The models receiving the concern act as they are supposed to, and the fact that `ZipWithCBSA` responds to `:store_locations` should be obvious in some capacity from `ZipWithCBSA`. It has nothing to do with the other models/concern. Props to Robert Nubel for making this obvious with his potential solutions.**

Is it possible to both has_many and belongs_to relationships in a single concern?

### Overview

I have a table `ZipWithCBSA` that essentially includes a bunch of zip code meta information.

I have two models that have zip codes: `StoreLocation` and `PriceSheetLocation`. Essentially:

```
class ZipWithCBSA < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = :zip
  has_many :store_locations, foreign_key: :zip
  has_many :price_sheet_locations, foreign_key: :zip
end

class StoreLocation< ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :zip_with_CBSA, foreign_key: :zip
  ...
end

class PriceSheetLocation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :zip_with_CBSA, foreign_key: :zip
  ...
end
```

There are two properties from `ZipWithCBSA` that I always want returned with my other models, including on `#index` pages. To prevent joining this table for each item every time I query it, I want to cache two of these fields into the models themselves -- i.e.

```
# quick schema overview~~~
ZipWithCBSA
  - zip
  - cbsa_name
  - cbsa_state
  - some_other_stuff
  - that_I_usually_dont_want
  - but_still_need_access_to_occasionally

PriceSheetLocation
  - store
  - zip
  - cbsa_name
  - cbsa_state

StoreLocation
  - zip
  - generic_typical
  - location_address_stuff
  - cbsa_name
  - cbsa_state
```

So, I've added

```
after_save :store_cbsa_data_locally, if: ->(obj){ obj.zip_changed? }
private
def store_cbsa_data_locally
  if zip_with_cbsa.present?
    update_column(:cbsa_name, zip_with_cbsa.cbsa_name)
    update_column(:cbsa_state, zip_with_cbsa.cbsa_state)
  else
    update_column(:cbsa_name, nil)
    update_column(:cbsa_state, nil)
  end
end
```

I'm looking to move these into concerns, so I've done:

```
# models/concerns/UsesCBSA.rb

module UsesCBSA
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    belongs_to :zip_with_cbsa, foreign_key: 'zip'

    after_save :store_cbsa_data_locally, if: ->(obj){ obj.zip_changed? }

    def store_cbsa_data_locally
      if zip_with_cbsa.present?
        update_column(:cbsa_name, zip_with_cbsa.cbsa_name)
        update_column(:cbsa_state, zip_with_cbsa.cbsa_state)
      else
        update_column(:cbsa_name, nil)
        update_column(:cbsa_state, nil)
      end
    end

    private :store_cbsa_data_locally

  end
end


# ~~models~~
class StoreLocation < ActiveRecord::Base
  include UsesCBSA
end

class PriceSheetLocation < ActiveRecord::Base
  include UsesCBSA
end
```

This is all working great-- but I still need to manually add the has_many relationships to the ZipWithCBSA model:

```
class ZipWithCBSA < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :store_locations, foreign_key: zip
  has_many :price_sheet_locations, foreign_key: zip
end
```

### Finally! The Question!

Is it possible to re-open `ZipWithCBSA` and add the `has_many` relationships from the concern? Or in any other more-automatic way that allows me to specify one single time that these particular series of models are bffs?

I tried

```
# models/concerns/uses_cbsa.rb
...
def ZipWithCBSA
  has_many self.name.underscore.to_sym, foregin_key: :zip
end
...
```

and also

```
# models/concerns/uses_cbsa.rb
...
ZipWithCBSA.has_many self.name.underscore.to_sym, foregin_key: :zip
...
```

but neither worked. I'm guessing it has to do with the fact that those relationships aren't added during the models own initialization... but **is it possible to define the relationship of a model in a separate file?**

I'm not very fluent in metaprogramming with Ruby yet.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't work that great-- I find myself in infinite loops...

Comment: I have fixed the recursion problem and adjusted the original question appropriately. I also didn't need all the references to `self.` so I removed them to help clean it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to add the relation onto your ZipWithCBSA model at the time your concern is included into the related models, using `class_exec` on the model class itself. E.g., inside the `included` block of your concern, add:

```
relation_name = self.table_name
ZipWithCBSA.class_exec do
  has_many relation_name, foreign_key: :zip
end
```

Comment: I end up receiving:

`NoMethodError: undefined method \`price_sheet_locations' for #<ZipWithCBSA:0x00000005d439b0>`

Which is the same problem I was receiving when trying the other approaches above. It's like the ZipWithCBSA class doesn't register the relationship methods.... or the relationship at all....

Comment: I figured out what's happening! The code in the concern isn't actually loaded until the receiving model is actually used. e.g. that relationship on ZipWithCBSA doesn't exist until I at least do a PriceSheetLocation.connection. Meaning if I try to do `ZipWithCBSA.find('90210').price_sheet_locations` -- it isn't registered until after I've at least done `PriceSheetLocation.first` or `.connection`.

Thanks a lot for the class_exec tip -- it ultimately accomplished what my original question saught. Unfortunately there are other new issues regarding timing.

Comment: @Mr.Tim There are a number of ways you can approach this. My first suggestion is just to add the relations onto ZipWithCBSA... metaprogramming is fun when you're writing it, but nightmarish when debugging it. If you really want to keep it magic, you could a) force Rails to eager-load all models on boot, for a drastic approach; or b) use a method missing hack on ZipWithCBSA, to force it to resolve your models before giving up; something like, `def method_missing(method, *args); method.to_s.singularize.capitalize.constantize rescue nil; super(*args); end`. Probably needs tweaking.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you completely. Thanks for your time today!